# Flutter override environment variables in unit tests

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, environment-variables

In my production code I set environment variables using the `--DART-DEFINE` flag and then retrieve them by using `String.fromEnvironment`.

How can I override the value returned by `String.fromEnvironment` in my unit tests, to test how my production code responds to different environment variable values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap your environment variables in a class and use your preferred dependency injection or service locator package (eg. [get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it)) to access your injected class from within your app.

Your `environment_config.dart`:

```dart
class EnvironmentConfig {

    final String someValue;

    EnvironmentConfig({
      required this.someValue,
    });

    factory EnvironmentConfig.init() {
      const someValue = String.fromEnvironment('someEnvVar');
      return EnvironmentConfig(someValue: someValue);
    }
  
}
```

`main.dart`

```dart
void main() {
    // instance can now be accessed from any class/widget within your app
    GetIt.I.registerSingleton<EnvironmentConfig>(EnvironmentConfig.init());

    runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Then within unit tests, you can inject your own instance of `EnvironmentConfig` with your own values:

```dart
void main() {
    setUp(() {
      final config = EnvironmentConfig(someValue: 'myCustomValue');
      GetIt.I.registerSingleton<EnvironmentConfig>(config);
    });

    tearDown(() {
      GetIt.I.reset();
    });

    test('Verify env vars', () {
      expect(GetIt.I<EnvironmentConfig>().someValue, equals('myCustomValue');
    });
}
```

**EDIT:** Given this is now the top result when searching for an answer to this, it's worth noting that the trade-off to the above approach is that it doesn't cater for tree-shaking, as the `EnvironmentConfig` class is not a compile-time constant when using the factory constructor.

Answer (score 3):

The `flutter test` command supports `--dart-define=NAME=VALUE`, but this is annoying to automate. It's also not possible to change dart defines at runtime.

What my team does is declare all of the dart defines in a single file, and use separate global variables to override them during tests:

```dart
String? fooDefineOverride;
String get fooDefine => fooDefineOverride ?? const String.fromEnvironment('foo');

void resetOverrides() {
  fooDefineOverride = null;
}
```

```dart
void main() {
  setUpAll(() {
    resetOverrides();
  });

  test('Foo is foobar', () {
    fooDefineOverride = 'foobar';
    // ... do tests
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two good answers here, but they do miss the point.

The point is:

The Question:

> How can I override the value returned by String.fromEnvironment in my unit tests

The onpoint, correct answer is:

You cannot do that.

You have to modify and complicate your code to make it testable.  The data structure that holds environmental data in Dart is read only, so it is impossible to do what you require in this language.